# Wrap JSX tags around renderItem? for <Flatlist> or <SectionList> in React-Native

Tags: react-native, accordion, react-native-flatlist, react-native-paper, react-native-sectionlist

Is there a way to put JSX tags around `renderItem`? (I want to put the rendered output from `renderItem` inside an Accordion drop-down using `<List.Accordion>` from "react-native-paper")

```js
<List.Accordion>
  <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
</List.Accordion>
```

This works; however as I am using a `ListHeaderComponent` and `ListFooterComponent` props; I only want the `<List.Accordion>` around the `renderItem`; so that the content of `renderItem` are inside an accordion (as a container) but not around the header and footer.

`Note: I am using SectionList, but I made the first example FlatList to simplify`

I tried the following which works; except for it not rendering inside a `<List.Accordion></List.Accordion>`:

```js
const AudioTracksScreenData = [
  {
        title: "Reviews",
        renderItem: renderReviews,
        data: audiobookReviewData.result,
        keyExtractor: reviewsKeyExtractor,
  },
]

<SectionList
  sections={AudioTracksScreenData}
  keyExtractor={({ section: { keyExtractor } }) => {
    keyExtractor;
  }}
  renderItem={({ section: { renderItem } }) => (
    <List.Accordion>{renderItem}</List.Accordion>
  )}
  ListHeaderComponent={getHeader()}
/>
```

- https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist
- https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist
- https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/list-accordion.html

I could get this to work using `<ScrollView>` and `.map()` ; However I am hoping there is a way to do this with `<SectionList>`.

[What I have...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNSRX.png)

[What I want...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSYPH.jpg) (a collapsible list if you press/click on reviews; ignore styling differences)